# Parse HTML in jquery through ajax into elements and replace each corresponding on page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following on an HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){refresh()},5000);
function refresh()
{
    $.post("test.php",
    {
           // nothing here             
    },
    function(data, textStatus)
    {      

      $('' + data + '').find('.maindiv').each(function () {
      $('.maindiv').replaceWith('.maindiv');
      });

    });  
}
</script>

<div id = "1" class= "maindiv">
<div sid= "1" class= "subdiv">old sub div content</div>
<div cid= "1" class= "childdiv">another old sub div</div>
<img id = "1" src="http://foo.com/bar.png"/>  
</div>

<div id = "2" class= "maindiv">
<div sid= "2" class= "subdiv">this content is old</div>
<div cid= "2" class= "childdiv">please update me!</div>
<img id= "2" src="http://foo.com/bar.png"/>  
</div>
```

The PHP page that gets called to update elements (test.php):

```
<?php

 echo '<div id = "1" class= "maindiv">
       <div sid= "1" class= "subdiv">this is new sub div</div>
       <div cid= "1" class= "childdiv">this is also new sub div content</div>
       <img id= "1" src="http://foo.com/bar.png"/>  
       </div>'; 

 echo '<div id = "2" class= "maindiv">
       <div sid= "2" class= "subdiv">new content</div>
       <div cid= "2" class= "childdiv">new content for this child div</div>
       <img id= "2" src="http://foo.com/bar.png"/>  
       </div>'; 
?>
```

These 2 elements are also present on the HTML page. Basically what I want to call the PHP page and get those elements from the PHP page and loop through them in the response in the HTML page and replace each maindiv (including all its child elements) with the corresponding one on the HTML page.

This is just a very basic example. I do this because the content changes in these elements and want to replace the elemnts like live update.

The function I'm posting seems to have no response so don't know how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although I believe it's allowed in HTML5, using ids that start with numbers won't work in some browsers.

Comment: i have to use numbers to be unique as there are a lot of interactions on the pages so they must be unique....anyway thanks for pointing this out @popnoodles

Comment: You can't prefix them with a non-numeric string? Anyway at least you know.

Comment: could do it like this after solving the above problem :)

Comment: These chunks of HTML look very similar. If that is how they all look  the most efficient way would be to use a template and return just the data you need to replace placeholders in the template.

Comment: it's actually much more complex than that :) this is just a very basic example to know the trick and then apply it to my own needs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the `maindiv` elements in page so that they match with the new elements.

Also need to modify what you are replacing with

```
 $(data ).filter('.maindiv').each(function (index) {/* filter or find depends on html structure sent*/
      /* "this" is the current div in response*/          
      $('#'+this.id).replaceWith(this);
});
```

`each` will track `index`, `eq()` is used to match same index in page.

**EDIT:** Also change `find()` to `filter()` if only output is the DIV's in root of output

Comment: The function works but there is something wrong as it doesn't match the `id` of the element being replaced and just replaces the first element with class `maindiv`. For example if on the HTML page i have ids 3,2,and 1 resepectively in this order and i have only id 1 on the PHP page..if i use the function like this, it will replace id3 on the page with id 1 as id 3 is the first `maindiv` present

Comment: OK, I modified answer to match ID's

Comment: This now works well :) one last question if i have an element called `maindiv` like the ones posted above but has another attribue called `gid` for example instead of the regular id, how to replace those also?? (some elements might have `id` and others might have `gid` but both have the same number...so how about replacing both??

Comment: Tried adding `$('#'+this.gid).replaceWith(this);` but it's not working

Comment: Nope sorry you can't understand me...i mean it's working with only id, how can i make it work with custom attriibutes not the regular id??

Comment: need to have consistency with your `maindiv` elements, and you show using ID for them. If you want to loop over their contents, that was never mentioned

Comment: just got the answer from another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773068/jquery-ajax-for-each-loop-custom-attributes

Comment: makes no sense why you show ID and want to use GID. Again, some cconsistency with server output will help. Looking for ID is far more efficient DOM search than using other attributes

Comment: i use both because there are a lot of interactions within the page like showing and hiding forms...and the divs have the same class but can't have the same id...would it be better if instead of gid use id="g1",id="g2" for example

Comment: yes...would be much better. Set up a convention for ID... is fastest and most efficient selector

Comment: for what you are doing should be using JSON and parsing results locally

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you have 1 div that surrounds the content that you want to poll then upon receiving the ajax response replace the whole block with `html()`

```
<?php 
//check for ajax and return
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest'){
    header('Content-Type: text/html');

    $response = '
    <div id = "a" class= "maindiv">
       <div sid= "1" class= "subdiv">'.date("D M j G:i:s T Y").'</div>
       <div cid= "1" class= "childdiv">'.md5(time()).'</div>
       <img id= "1" src="http://foo.com/bar.png"/>  
    </div>
    <div id = "a" class= "maindiv">
       <div sid= "1" class= "subdiv">'.date("D M j G:i:s T Y").'</div>
       <div cid= "1" class= "childdiv">'.md5(time()+1).'</div>
       <img id= "1" src="http://foo.com/bar.png"/>  
    </div>'; 

    echo $response;
    die;
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function poll(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({ url: "./test.php", cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#polling").html( data );
            poll();
        }});
    }, 5000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    poll();
});
</script>


<div id = "polling" class= "maindiv">
    <!--New response will replace the below html-->
    <div id = "1" class= "maindiv">
    <div sid= "1" class= "subdiv">old sub div content</div>
    <div cid= "1" class= "childdiv">another old sub div</div>
    <img id = "1" src="http://foo.com/bar.png"/>  
    </div>

    <div id = "2" class= "maindiv">
    <div sid= "2" class= "subdiv">this content is old</div>
    <div cid= "2" class= "childdiv">please update me!</div>
    <img id= "2" src="http://foo.com/bar.png"/>  
    </div> 

</div>
```

### Edit

You can also return json and then loop the response into the divs based on id
Here is an example:

```
<?php 
//check for ajax and return
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest'){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $response = array(
    'block_a'=>'content for block a (last_updated:)'.date("D M j G:i:s T Y"),
    'block_b'=>'content for block b (last_updated:)'.date("D M j G:i:s T Y"),
    'block_c'=>'content for block c (last_updated:)'.date("D M j G:i:s T Y"),
    'block_d'=>'content for block d (last_updated:)'.date("D M j G:i:s T Y"),
    'block_e'=>'content for block e (last_updated:)'.date("D M j G:i:s T Y"),
    ); 

    echo json_encode($response);
    die;
}
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
function poll(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({ url: "./test.php", cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                //key value place html blocks
                $("#"+k).html(v);
            });
            poll();
        }, dataType: "json"});
    }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    poll();
});
</script>


<div id = "block_a" class= "maindiv"></div>
<div id = "block_b" class= "maindiv"></div>
<div id = "block_c" class= "maindiv"></div>
<div id = "block_d" class= "maindiv"></div>
<div id = "block_e" class= "maindiv"></div>
```

This way you can build `$response` with only the content you want replaced upon each poll.

Comment: because simply this is a very basic example :) what I actually do i want to send the only certain ids like for example send ids 2,4 out of 1,2,3,4 and update those 2,4 elements with their new content so want an id specific response

Comment: thanks for your effort Lawrence...i chose Charlie's answer for simplicity...thanks :)