# JQUERY AJAX for each loop custom attributes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This question is related to another one I asked yesterday and its link is:
[Parse HTML in jquery through ajax into elements and replace each corresponding on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764582/parse-html-in-jquery-through-ajax-into-elements-and-replace-each-corresponding-o)

Basically i want to call a php page with ajax and replace the elements in the response with the corresponding ones on the page. I got the following function in an answer:

```
 $(data ).filter('.maindiv').each(function (index) 
  /* "this" is the current div in response*/          
  $('#'+this.id).replaceWith(this);
 });
```

The above function woeks well when the div I want to replace has a regular id= but if use a custom attribute like gid= for example it won't work. How can i fix this??

Thanks

Comment: you should consider using the [data-](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attribute introduced with html5 for custom attributes

Comment: I don't quite understand you. You are asking how to select the divs that are already on the page using something other than the id? You can take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: nope...some elements on the page have the attribue id and some have the attribure gid but both have class called `maindiv` so when i call the php i want to get what's in there and replace items that match on the html...if an element has `<div id='1' class='maindiv'` it should replace this and if an element has `<div gid='1' class='maindiv'` it should replace the one with the same class and attribute and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select node with a gid attribute with:

```
$('[gid]').replaceWith(this);
```

you can even be more precise by selecting only the node which has the gid value you want

```
$('[gid="hello"]').replaceWith(this);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I think something wrong it here...i tried `$('.maindiv[gid]').replaceWith(this);`. It's replacing the correct div but it's replacing it twice....i don't know why it does that...also tried now `$('.maindiv[id]').replaceWith(this);` but it's replacing all .maindiv that have the attribute id without matching the same id

Comment: how to make sure the response matches only the same id or gid??

Comment: Something like that should work $('[gid="' + $(this).attr('gid') + '"]').replaceWith(this);

Answer (score 2):

Use attr for custom attribute instead of using `this.id` you can use `$(this).attr("YourAttr")`;

```
$(data ).filter('.maindiv').each(function (index) 
   /* "this" is the current div in response*/          
    $('#'+$(this).attr('gid')).replaceWith(this);
});
```

Comment: "when the **div I want to replace** has a regular id= but if use a custom attribute like gid..." It seems to me like you have it backwards there. You need to select by the custom attr. Edit: Roger C's answer shows what I meant.

Comment: the div in the PHP page is `<div gid='4' class='maindiv'` so I want to replace the one matching on the html page which is also `<div gid='4' class='maindiv'` but instead it replaces `<div id='4' class='maindiv'` so don't know why it does that

Answer (score 0):

For data you can use a custom attribute. [HTML5 specificies](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) the use of a `data-` attribute. The cool thing is that this works in HTML4 too! jQuery can read it by using the data method.

I'll recommend:

```
<div class="maindiv" data-grid="myGrid">...</div>

$(data).filter('.maindiv').each(function (index)        
     $('#'+$(this).data('gid')).replaceWith(this);
});
```